# Selecting a number from natural number < n excluding a possibility

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given n natural number starts from 0, and  `b` which is a number in between 0 to n
I wish to randomly select a number excluding `b`.

Say n is 5
then The number to be selected is `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`
say b is 4,

then my random selection is from `{0,1,2,3,5}`

A way to do this is to do a while loop, until the random.nextInteger() does not find a 4.

Is there a easy to to do this other than using a while loop?

Comment: I guess you mean you want a random *uniformly distributed* number. Is that correct?

Comment: @amit yes that would be great

Comment: did you google or search to see if it's asked before?

Comment: Is this C# or java ? `nextInteger()` does not exist in C# ...

Answer (score 2):

I would write a simple extension:

```
// N.B. : min is inclusive, max is exclusive; so range is: [min,max) - {toExclude}
public static int Next(this Random rand, int min, int max, int toExclude)
{
    int v = rand.Next(min, max - 1);
    if (v < toExclude)
        return v;
    return v + 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
var random = new Random();
var val = random.Next(0,6,4); // 6 because max is exclusive in C# random.Next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is the best in my optinion. It is simple and elegant, and even for `m=2` it is `O(1)` on average (The expected number of redraws is `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + .... < 1`).

If you want to avoid the worst case of infinite loop there is an alternative, though I doubt it will have real performance impact.

1. draw a random double in range [0,1]. let it be `d`. If `d < b/m`: draw a number in range [0,b) and return it.
2. Else (`d > b/m`) - draw a random number in range `[b+1,m]` and return it.

Note, it is indeed uniform distributed because:

There are `m+1` numbers in range `0,...,m`, but only `m` "valid" numbers (excluding `b`).

There are `b` numbers in range `0,1,...,b-1` - so the probability of the number being in this range assuming uniform distribution is `b/m` - which is exactly `P(d < b/m)`.

In java it will look similar to this:

```
int m = 5, b = 4;
Random r = new Random();
double d = r.nextDouble();
if (d < ((double)b)/m) {
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(b));
} else { 
    System.out.println(r.nextInt(m-b) + b + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach if you prefer:

```
import random

def random_unifrom(n,b):
    assert b < n and n > 0 and b > 0
    nMinusOneList = [i for i in range(n) if i != b]    
    lSize = len(nMinusOneList)
    randIndex = random.randint(0, lSize-1)
    return nMinusOneList[randIndex]
```

I wrote this in python just for simplicity.
creating the nMinusOneList has complexity of O(n).
returning the random index complexity depends on the random function you are using.

At the end, you loose nothing if you take this approach instead of a while loop, but even if you use the while loop approach, if the random function is random (!!) then you should not have a problem. However, my approach above excludes the number you do not need from the very beginning.

In C#, the one line I use in python might be a couple of lines which consists of a for loop on the range 0 to n, with a condition that the x (for loop index) does not equal to b, in building the list, and then you will have the list that excludes b.